# ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list(ACL)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle Xe database 18 and apex 21, then when trying to create REST Data Sources, it gave me the following message (ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)).
Please How I can resolve this problem step by step ?

Thanks

Comment: Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67601330/how-to-whitelist-ip-address-to-access-oracle-database/67612564#67612564

Comment: Thanks but still not working.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It works for me, so I hoped it'll work for you too.

Comment: Try to allow '*' - all hosts for debug.

Comment: This note Known Issues When Apparently Correctly Configured ACLs Fail Don't Prevent the ORA-24247 Error (Doc ID 1074843.1) can be helpful.
Also take a look at https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-enhancements-12cr1

But in order to triage the issue, could you please indicate what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

As sysdba

```
DECLARE
  l_acl       VARCHAR2(100) := 'acl_name.xml';
  l_desc      VARCHAR2(100) := 'ACL DESCRIPTION';
  l_principal VARCHAR2(30)  := 'USERNAME'; -- UPPERCASE
  l_host      VARCHAR2(100) := 'domain.com'; --host
BEGIN
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(l_acl, l_desc, l_principal, TRUE, 'connect');
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege(l_acl, l_principal, TRUE, 'resolve');
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(l_acl, l_host);
 
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for you Enrique Flores. Helpful.